# How to ensure that we lose no rows during pd.merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

df1:                                 df2:

```
  Column1  Column2  Column3           ColumnA  ColumnB ColumnC
0    a        x        x            0    c        y       y
1    c        x        x            1    e        z       z
2    e        x        x            2    a        s       s
3    d        x        x            3    d        f       f
4    h        x        x
5    k        x        x
```

df1.merge(df2,left_on='Column1', right_on='ColumnA')

how to know that rows with h and k are going to be lost ?

I'm aware of the how='left' option on the pd.merge function but how can I identify values that have no match and performing the inner join at the same time ?

do I need to first do the how='left', then print the column1 where columnA is NaN, then remove these ?

**EDIT**

the use case is the following :  a customer provides 2 files, saying that column1 from file 1 will always have a match in column A of file 2.

then, we want a safe way to assert that, printing an error message when this is violated

Comment: In response to your last question- Yes, but what's the use case? Printing is likely not the best way.

Comment: What is the end goal? to know which values from `df1['Column1]` will be missing in an inner join?

Comment: @MattR : I edit the question to tell the end goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need find all values which are different use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
a = df1.loc[~df1['Column1'].isin(df2['ColumnA']), 'Column1']
print (a)
4    h
5    k
Name: Column1, dtype: object
```

And for check is possible count `True`s in inverse mask and compare with `0`:

```
a = (~df1['Column1'].isin(df2['ColumnA'])).sum() == 0
print (a)
False
```

---

For faster solution use `numpy` with [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
a = np.setdiff1d(df1['Column1'], df2['ColumnA'])
print (a)
['h' 'k']

a = len(np.setdiff1d(df1['Column1'], df2['ColumnA'])) == 0
print (a)
False
```

Comment: is it faster to do that vs doing the pd.merge(how=left) and then removing the Nan ?

Comment: I think yes, the best test it in real data.

Comment: @ChristopheBlin, You can always check the timing differences between the various methods. But my assumption would be that the `.isin()` solution fits your needs perfectly. It will return everything from `df1` that is not in `df2` between those two columns.